# AWS boto3 page_iterator.search can't compare datetime.datetime to str

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

Trying to capture delta files(files created after last processing) sitting on s3. To do that using boto3 filter iterator by query LastModified value rather than returning all the list of files and filtering on the client site.

According to http://jmespath.org/?, the below query is valid and filters the following json respose;

```
filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search(
"Contents[?LastModified>='datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 27, 8, 5, 37, tzinfo=tzutc())'].Key")

for key_data in filtered_iterator:
print(key_data)
```

However it fails with;

```
RuntimeError: xxxxxxx has failed: can't compare datetime.datetime to str
```

Sample paginator reponse;

```
{
"Contents": [{
    "LastModified": "datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 28, 8, 5, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())",
    "ETag": "1022dad2540da33c35aba123476a4622",
    "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
    "Key": "blah1/blah11/abc.json",
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "App-AWS",
        "ID": "bfc77ae78cf43fd1b19f24f99998cb86d6fd8220dbfce0ce6a98776253646656"
    },
    "Size": 623
}, {
    "LastModified": "datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 28, 8, 5, 37, tzinfo=tzutc())",
    "ETag": "1022dad2540da33c35abacd376a44444",
    "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
    "Key": "blah2/blah22/xyz.json",
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "App-AWS",
        "ID": "bfc77ae78cf43fd1b19f24f99998cb86d6fd8220dbfce0ce6a81234e632c5a8c"
    },
    "Size": 702
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Boto3 Jmespath implementation does not support dates filtering (it will mark them as incompatible types "unicode" and "datetime" in your example). But by the way Dates are parsed by Amazon you can perform lexographical comparison of them using to_string() method of Jmespath.

Something like this:

```
"Contents[?to_string(LastModified)>='\"2015-01-01 01:01:01+00:00\"']"
```

But keep in mind that its a lexographical comparison and not dates comparison. Works most of the time tho.

Answer (score 6):

After spend a few minutes on [boto3 paginator](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/paginators.html) documentation, I just realist it is actually an syntax problem, which I overlook it as a string.

Actually, the quote that embrace comparison value on the right is a `backquote`/[backtick](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backtick), symbol **[ ` ]** . You cannot use single quote **[ ' ]** for the comparison values/objects.

After inspect [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/examples.html) example, I notice it is using backquote for comparative value. So boto3 paginator implementation indeed comply to JMESPath standard.

Here is the code I run without error using the backquote.

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3_paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects')
s3_iterator = s3_paginator.paginate(Bucket='mytestbucket')
filtered_iterator = s3_iterator.search(
    "Contents[?LastModified >= `datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 27, 8, 5, 37, tzinfo=tzutc())`].Key"
    )
for key_data in filtered_iterator:
    print(key_data)
```

Comment: JMESPATH supports datetime.datetime; Please grap the response in my initial question and use this on the jmespath;  Contents[?LastModified>='datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 27, 8, 5, 37, tzinfo=tzutc())'].Key

Comment: @East2West  The response syntax is a JSON , and it is not a datetime object, but datetime string.   That's why it show the error : `can't compare datetime.datetime to str`

Comment: filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search(
                "Contents[?LastModified>='"+str(datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 27, 8, 5, 37))+"'].Key")      returns the very same error....

Comment: @East2West : Please pass the datetime object without quotation.

Comment: i get this when i dont use quotation: RuntimeError: getListOfS3Files has failed: Invalid token.: Parse error at column 24, token "2016" (NUMBER), for expression:
"Contents[?LastModified>=2016-12-27 08:05:37].Key"

Comment: @East2West : I just found out the actual problem.