# Boto3: How to get newest docker image from ECR?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, boto3, amazon-ecr

I want to get the newest Docker image from ECR using `boto3`. Currently I'm using [describe_images](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.describe_images) method from the `ecr` client and I get a dictionary with `imageDetails`

```
import boto3

registry_name = 'some_registry_name_in_aws'

client = boto3.client('ecr')

response = client.describe_images(
    repositoryName=registry_name,
)
```

there's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331418/aws-cli-ecr-list-images-get-newest) for this using `aws-cli`, but documentation don't describe any `--query` argument that can be passed to `describe_images`. So, how can I get the newest docker image from ECR using boto3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

You need to use a paginator on `describe_images` and a `JMESPath` expression

```
import boto3

registry_name = 'some_registry_name_in_aws'
jmespath_expression = 'sort_by(imageDetails, &to_string(imagePushedAt))[-1].imageTags'

client = boto3.client('ecr')

paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_images')

iterator = paginator.paginate(repositoryName=registry_name)
filter_iterator = iterator.search(jmespath_expression)
result = list(filter_iterator)[0]
result
>>>
'latest_image_tag'
```

### Explanation

After reading the cli [describe-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/describe-images.html) documentation find out that

> describe-images is a paginated operation.

and `boto3` can provide you a paginated operation on specific methods with [get_paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.get_paginator) method.

However, if you try to apply the `JMESPath` expression `'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]'` directly, you'll get an error because the result from `imagePushedAt` is a `datetime.datetime` object and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584793/aws-boto3-page-iterator-search-cant-compare-datetime-datetime-to-str/45149339#45149339)

> Boto3 Jmespath implementation does not support dates filtering

so, you need to cast `imagePushedAt` to string `'sort_by(imageDetails, &to_string(imagePushedAt))[-1].imageTags'`.

Comment: This works well, but beware that the sorting is applied on a per-page basis. 
For ECR registries containing more than 100 images, you should specify a larger PageSize to avoid duplicate results (one per page):
`iterator = client_paginator.paginate(repositoryName=registry_name, PaginationConfig={'PageSize': 1000})`